# Count number of m-subsets with xor = 0

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

Given positive integers $n$ and $m$, count the $m$-subsets $S\subseteq[2^n - 1]$ such that the bitwise XOR of the members of $S$ is $0$, where as usual for any positive integer $k$ we let $[k]=\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$.

For example, for $n = 2$, $m = 3$ the answer is $1$: $\{1, 2, 3\}$ is the only set that meets the restrictions.

It seems that it could be done faster than using brute force, perhaps with dynamic programming.

There is a question in which $S$ is allowed to range over all subsets of $[2^n-1]$ irrespective of their cardinalities, but I couldn't figure out how to generalize it in order to have the fixed size of subset: [Count subsets with zero sum of xors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158584/count-subsets-with-zero-sum-of-xors?rq=1)

I also tried to reduct the problem to the system of linear equations, but our sets are not multisets, so this approach doesn't work.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Are you asking how many subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots, 2^{n-1}\}$ have cardinality $m$ and the result of the bitwise xor of all the members of the subset is $1$? Is that $2^{n-1}$ or $2^n-1$? And is that xor result just $1$ or the number with all $1$'s, namely $2^n-1$?

Comment: It was a typo, I meant 0, not 1.

Comment: OK, that answers one of my questions. And the rest?

Comment: Yes, how many subsets with 0 bitwise xor have this cardinality. It is 2^n - 1.

Comment: You'll probably want to post mathematical expressions sooner or later.  See the introduction here about [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$ on the site.